# openACC pgc++ vs pgcc, error at linking

Tags: cuda, openacc, cufft

I downloaded the example from https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/tutorials/mixing-openacc-with-gpu-libraries/ 
The codes are given in the above mwntioned links

1) using pgcc

```
pgc++ -c cuFFT.cu
pgcc -acc   -Mcudalib=cufft fft.c cufft.o
works perfectly fine
```

2) using pgc++

```
pgc++ -c cuFFT.cu
pgc++ -acc   -Mcudalib=cufft fft.cpp (or .c samefiles) cufft.o
```

I get the following error

```
    undefined reference to launchCUFFT(float*, int, void*)
     pgacclnk: child process exit status 1: /usr/bin/ld
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a C/C++ linking mismatch.

To get this to work in PGI 17.9 tools I had to:

1. rename cuFFT.cu to cuFFT.cpp
2. edit the malloc line in fft.c from:

   ```
   float *data = malloc(2*n*sizeof(float));
   ```

   to:

   ```
   float *data = (float *)malloc(2*n*sizeof(float));
   ```
3. modify the declaration in fft.c from:

   ```
   extern void launchCUFFT(float *d_data, int n, void *stream);
   ```

   to:

   ```
   extern "C" void launchCUFFT(float *d_data, int n, void *stream);
   ```
4. Issue the following compile commands:

   ```
   $ pgc++ -c cuFFT.cpp
   $ pgc++ -acc   -Mcudalib=cufft fft.c cuFFT.o
   ```

Comment: step 3 is the key for the undefined reference error you show in your question.

Comment: sorry I meant step 3. as step 2 gives a compiler error. I have fixed that one